# Accessing the Openstack API in Bluemix

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, ibm-cloud

For the VM capability in Bluemix, is it possible to use the OpenStack API? If so, how do you access it?

I'm trying to use these URLs :

- https://keystone2.open.ibmcloud.com/v2.0/tokens (POST) with this payload:

  ```
  {"auth": {
     "tenantName": "myTenant", 
     "passwordCredentials": {"username": "myUser", "password": "myPwd"}
  } }
  ```
- https://keystone2.open.ibmcloud.com/v3/auth/tokens (POST) with this payload :

  ```
  { "auth": { "identity": { 
      "methods": [ "password" ], 
      "password": { "user": { "id": "myID", "password": "myPWD" } }
   } } }
  ```

In both cases, I get this answer:

```
 error: {
    message: "KS-58299FC La requête que vous avez faite nécessite une authentification."
    code: 401
    title: "Unauthorized"
}
```

What's my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login using the OpenStack credentials, not your Bluemix ID. To see those credentials, in the Bluemix dashboard, go to Mange Organization > Manage Infrastructure, and select Show Credentials. It will display data that looks something like this:

```
{
    "auth_url": "https://keystone2.open.ibmcloud.com",
    "tenant": "TENANT",
    "credentials": {
        "username": "USER",
        "password": "PWD"
    }
}
```

Then run the command with the body you had, but using these credentials:

```
{"auth": {
   "tenantName": "TENANT", 
   "passwordCredentials": {"username": "USER", "password": "PWD"}
} }
```

Comment: To which URL do you send this payload?

Answer (score 1):

This should be the POST body looks like if you want to get the auth token:

```
    {
        "auth": {
            "tenantName": "demo",
            "passwordCredentials": {
                "username": "demo",
                "password": "secretsecret"
            }
        }
    }
```

and the URL should be: https://keystone2.open.ibmcloud.com/v2.0/tokens

Please refer: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-identity-v2.html

After got the token you can access all the resources provide by OpenStack.